# Why does QGraphicsItem::scenePos() keep returning (0,0)

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have been toying with this piece of code:

```
QGraphicsLineItem * anotherLine = this->addLine(50,50, 100, 100);
qDebug() << anotherLine->scenePos();

QGraphicsLineItem * anotherLine2 = this->addLine(80,10, 300, 300);
qDebug() << anotherLine2->scenePos();
```

Where the `this` pointer refers to a `QGraphicsScene`. In both cases, I get `QPointF(0,0)` for both output.
From reading the document, I thought `scenePos()` is supposed to return the position of the line within the scene, not where it is within its local coordinate system. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After reading the QT 4.5 documentation carefully on [addLine](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qgraphicsscene.html#addLine), I realize what I have been doing wrong. According to the doc:

> Note that the item's geometry is
>   provided in item coordinates, and its
>   position is initialized to (0, 0)

So if I specify addLine(50,50, 100, 100), I am actually modifying its local item coordinate. The assumption I made that it will be treated as a scene coordinate is wrong or unfounded. What I should be doing is this

```
// Create a line of length 100
QGraphicsItem * anotherLine = addLine(0,0, 100, 100); 

// move it to where I want it to be within the scene
anotherLine->setPos(50,50);
```

So if I am adding a line by drawing within the scene, I need to reset its centre to (0,0) then use setPos() to move it to where I want it to be in the scene.

Hope this helps anyone who stumble upon the same problem.

Comment: I've spent one afternoon hunting this down! Thank you so much! (even if this thread is 3 years old)