# Point 0/0 of QGraphicsItem.scene() (restricting item movement)

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have a problem limiting the move of my QGraphicItems:

```
QVariant CustomRectItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant& value)
{
    if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange && this->scene()) {

        // parameter value is the new position
        QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
        QRectF rect = this->scene()->sceneRect();

        // keep the item inside the scene rect
        if (!rect.contains(newPos)) {
            if(newPos.x() < rect.x())
                newPos.setX(rect.x());
            return newPos;
        }
    }
    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

This code should prevent an item from beeing dragged to the left of the scene
and thereby increasing it's size. It kinda works.
My problem is:

I insert to items when the scene is created.
On sits at x=0 (scene coord.) the other at x=10 (scene coord.)
With this code I CAN NOT drag the second item left of x=10.

It seems as if the call to **QGraphicsItem::scene()** returns different scenes for both items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer in this thread:
[Why does QGraphicsItem::scenePos() keep returning (0,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151849/qt-4-5-why-does-a-qgraphicsitemscenepos-keeps-returning-0-0)

The problem was located in the CREATION of the items.
Be careful to NOT position them in the constructor. One must position them after appearing in the scene...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
        item = new CustomRectItem(0, 0, 20, 20);
        item->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable |
                       QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
        scene->addItem(item);
        item->setPos(i*30, j*30);
    }
}
```